# Navigation via button click in Angular 10

Tags: button, onclick, navigation

I have a list of names that I want to show only 5 of them on every page. Users can see the next 5 names by pressing “Next” button.
How can I set the click attribute of a button to do this for me in Angular.

Here is my .html file:

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table" >
  <tbody *ngFor="let name of names.slice(index, index+ 5)">
    <tr>   <td>{{ name.value}} </td> </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style ="float: left" (click)="previousFunction()"> < Previous </button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style ="float: right" (click)="nextFunction()"> Next > </button>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was quiet easy to solve ...

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table" >
  <tbody *ngFor="let name of names.slice(index, index+ 5)">
    <tr>   <td>{{ name.value}} </td> </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style ="float: left" (click)="previousFunction($event, index)"> < Previous </button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style ="float: right" (click)="nextFunction($event, index)"> Next > </button>
</div>
```

and here is the .ts code:

```
export class AppComponent {
 constructor() { }
   index: number = 0;
   pageSize: number = 5;
   names = [
       { name: 'a'},
       { name: 'b'},
       { name: 'c'},
       { name: 'd'},
       { name: 'e'},
       { name: 'f'},
       { name: 'g'},
       { name: 'h'},
       { name: 'i'},
       { name: 'j' },

   ];

   previousFunction($event: any, count: any){
     this.index = count - this.pageSize
   }
   nextFunction($event: any, count: any){
     this.index = count + this.pageSize
   }
```